# Sanity.io field-level localisation

Tags: schema, sanity

I need to have proper localisation for my Sanity CMS.

I found the official information [here](https://www.sanity.io/docs/localization), but it doesn't get into details. I tried to apply the same approach for `block` type:

```
export default {
  title: 'Localised block',
  name: 'localeBlock',
  type: 'object',
  fieldsets: [
    {
      title: 'Translations',
      name: 'translations',
      options: {
        collapsible: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  fields: supportedLanguages.map(lang => ({
    title: lang.title,
    name: lang.id,
    type: 'block',
    fieldset: lang.isDefault ? null : 'translations',
  })),
}
```

But I got the following error:

```
Object type "localeBlock"
localeBlock:object → fields → block:block
Found unknown properties for block declaration: "fieldset"
```

How do I implement `block` localisation? Is there a deeper documentation on localisation than the official one?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the `Block` [docs](https://www.sanity.io/docs/block-type):

> In order to activate the block content editor for Sanity Studio, you must make an **array of blocks**

This means that the configuration should be:

```
export default {
  title: 'Localised block',
  name: 'localeBlock',
  type: 'object',
  fieldsets: [
    {
      title: 'Translations',
      name: 'translations',
      options: {
        collapsible: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  fields: supportedLanguages.map(lang => ({
    title: lang.title,
    name: lang.id,
    type: 'array',
    of: [{
      type: 'block'
    }],
    fieldset: lang.isDefault ? null : 'translations',
  })),
}
```